# xdebug.dump.* to php error log

Tags: php, xdebug

I don't have a problem with xdebug.dump.SERVER, .GET, etc displaying on the page, however these are not logged in the php error log file or the xdebug.trace file, though the rest of the stack trace information is logged correctly in the correct places, just nothing from xdebug.dump.*

I've tried to search for a reason or whether or not it's even possible, and went over the documentation several times, but it's hard to find or maybe nobody else has had this problem.

So is it possible to log the contents of xdebug.dump.SERVER, .GET, etc along with the rest of the log and/or trace information instead of only displaying it?

Here's my xdebug configuration:

```
xdebug.auto_trace = 1
xdebug.default_enable = 1
xdebug.extended_info=1
xdebug.collect_params=4
xdebug.dump.SERVER = REMOTE_ADDR,REQUEST_METHOD,REQUEST_URI
xdebug.dump.COOKIE = *
xdebug.dump.ENV = *
xdebug.dump.FILES = *
xdebug.dump.GET = *
xdebug.dump.POST = *
xdebug.dump_globals = 1
xdebug.dump_once = 1
xdebug.trace_format = 0
xdebug.trace_options = 1
xdebug.trace_output_dir="/var/www/.logs/xdebug"
xdebug.trace_output_name"tracelog"
```